# Author index building and footfullcite command

Tags: biblatex, citing, indexing, xindy

I use `biblatex` for managing my bibliography with `indexing=true`. I build an author index via the following code:

```
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\index[perso]}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiven}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}
```

In the text I use `\footcite` and `\footfullcite` for citing some documents.
Unfortunately, since I use the `\foocite` command I obtain the right index but when I use `\footfullcite` the index is not building well (the occurrence corresponding to `\footfullcite` does not appear in the index).

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[english]{article} 
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
texindy
]{indextools}
\makeindex
\makeindex[columnseprule,intoc=true,title=Index,name=perso]


\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\index[perso]}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiveni}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}

\begin{document}
\footcite{book}\newpage
\footfullcite{book}\newpage
\cite{article}\newpage
\footcite{article}\newpage
\footfullcite{article}
\printbibliography
\printindex[perso]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the solution could be `\AtEveryCitekey{\usebibmacro{citeindex}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default definition of `\footfullcite` does not include a call to the indexing macro, so its citations don't go into the index.

With

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

We add the call to `\usebibmacro{citeindex}` so that now these citations should also feature in the index.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference with `\AtEveryCitekey{\usebibmacro{citeindex}}` which lead in my case to the same result?

Comment: @Guuk Not a lot. My solution only injects the macro into the cite command it is missing from. Your solution adds it to all cite macros, even those that already call `citeindex` anyway - you end up with double the calls to the index in these cases (as can be seen in the `.idx` that gets unnecessarily longer), but the result is the same.