# Exclude item in automatic index

Tags: biblatex, indexing, xindy, authorindex

Based on the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390682/author-index-building-and-footfullcite-command), I used the following code

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

for generating an index of the authors of my document. Unfortunately, I am studying an author and I cite it many times in the text its name appears a lot of time in the index.

Is there any solution to hide a specific entry in the index automatically? :-)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[english]{article} 
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
texindy
]{indextools}
\makeindex
\makeindex[columnseprule,intoc=true,title=Index,name=perso]


\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\index[perso]}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiveni}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}

\begin{document}
\index[perso]{check}
\index[perso]{checkb} 
\index[perso]{check} 
\index[perso]{checkb} 
\index[perso]{checkb}
\footcite{book}\newpage
\footfullcite{book}\newpage
\cite{article}\newpage
\footcite{article}\newpage
\footfullcite{article}
\printbibliography
\printindex[perso]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even if it's based on the other question, please post a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) here, too.

Comment: Based on which specifics should a citation be hidden?

Comment: @Skillmon Based for instance on the author name? Or any specified key (like `check` or `checkb` in my MWE).

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear to me what entries you want to exclude. But you can add rather easily a test to the citeindex macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{book}{}
      {\indexnames{labelname}%
       \indexfield{indextitle}}}
    {}}
```

Comment: For instance, I want to remove entry associated `Buchautor, H.-W.` associated to the bib item `book`.

Comment: That's what my test above does.

Comment: Not totally, in fact, the book `Buchautor, H.-W.` is also obtained since the bibliography is built and then it add an item in the index.

Comment: but if you want to exclude several keys this might get tedious.

Comment: @guuk add the test to the index formattinh instead to completely remove the key as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @Skillmon: instead of a test for a field string one can also add a test for a category or a keywork.

Comment: You can disable the indexing of the bibliography by using `indexing=cite` instead of `indexing=true`. If you want to disable if only for one author: there is the equivalent bibindex macro.

Comment: Effectively I want to do for only one author...

Comment: Idea using `xstring`: `\newcommand{\indexP}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{Buchautor}{}{\index[perso]{#1}}}` (new index command) and `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\indexP}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiveni}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}` (new biblatex command for declaring and formatting the index based on names)

Comment: Currently it seems to work... I will debug it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better alternative to do this, but you could assign a category to a key which shouldn't cause an index. Sadly, this requires a change of all used citation macros. The following applies this change to the definition of `\footfullcite` you provided. Note that the key still shows up in the index for the page of the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[english]{article} 
%\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75},
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
texindy
]{indextools}
\makeindex
\makeindex[columnseprule,intoc=true,title=Index,name=perso]


\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
    indexing=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{noindex}% create the new category
\addtocategory{noindex}{book}% add the key `book` to that category


\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifcategory{noindex}{}{\usebibmacro{citeindex}}% only if not in noindex
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\index[perso]}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiveni}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}

\begin{document}
\footfullcite{book}\newpage
\footfullcite{book}\newpage
\footfullcite{article}\newpage
\footfullcite{article}\newpage
\footfullcite{article}
\printbibliography
\printindex[perso]
\end{document}
```

To remove the key entirely from the index, you could insert the `\ifcategory` check in the `\DeclareIndexNameFormat`-definition:

```
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\ifcategory{noindex}{}{
\nameparts{#1}%
\usebibmacro{index:name}%
{\index[perso]}%
{\namepartfamily}%
{\namepartgiveni}%
% {}% L1
% {}% L2
{\namepartprefix}% generates spurious space L3
{\namepartsuffix}% generates spurious space L4
}}
```

You could do the same based on the bib file and not inside of the tex-file by introducing a keyword if you like that approach more. The contents of the `\jobname.bib` file become:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75},
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000},
  keywords = {noindex}
}
\end{filecontents}
```

Just change the check `\ifcategory` to `\ifkeyword` the rest remains untouched.